# using `%*` after `shift`

Tags: windows, batch-file

I understand that in a Windows batch file, `%*` expands to all the command-line arguments, and that `shift` shifts the numbered command-line arguments `%1`, `%2`, etc. but that it does *not* change the content of `%*`.

What do I do if I want a version of `%*` that *does* reflect the effect of `shift`?   I understand I could just say `%1 %2 %3 %4 %5 %6 %7 %8 %9` after shifting but it seems stupid and potentially dangerous that that limits me to a fixed number of arguments.

Although this is not a python-specific question, it may help to understand that the reason I want this behaviour is that I've had to write a batch file  `SelectPython.bat` that pre-configures certain environment variables, in order to navigate the babel of different Python distros I have (you have to set `%PYTHONHOME%`, `%PYTHONPATH%` and `%PATH%` in certain ways before you can call the Python binary and have confidence that you'll get the right distro).   My current script works fine for setting these variables, but I would like to be able to call it *and* Python in one line - e.g.:

```
SelectPython C:\Python35  pythonw.exe myscript.py arg1 arg2 arg3 ...
```

Ideally I want my batch file to use `shift` to "eat" the first argument, process it accordingly and set up the environment, and then just automatically chain-execute the string formed by rest of the arguments.  The principle is analogous to the way `env` wraps commands in posix systems:

```
env FOO=1 echo $FOO     # wrap the `echo` command to be executed in the context of specified environment settings
```

So far I have this - the last line is where the problem is:

```
@echo off
set "LOC=%CD%
if not "%~1" == "" set "LOC=%~1
if exist "%LOC%\python.exe" goto :Success

echo "python.exe not found in %LOC%"
goto :eof

:Success
:: Canonicalize the resulting path:
pushd %LOC%
set "LOC=%CD%
popd

:: Let Python know where its own files are:
set "PYTHONHOME=%LOC%
set "PYTHONPATH=%LOC%;%LOC%\Lib\site-packages

:: Put Python's location at the beginning of the system path if it's not there already:
echo "%PATH%" | findstr /i /b /c:"%PYTHONHOME%" > nul || set "PATH=%PYTHONHOME%;%PYTHONHOME%\Scripts;%PATH%

:: Now execute the rest:
shift
if "%~1" == "" goto :eof
%1 %2 %3 %4 %5 %6 %7 %8 %9
:: This is unsatsifactory - what if there are more than 9 arguments?
```

**UPDATE:**  Thanks to [Stephan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2152082/stephan) my working solution now has the following altered end-section:

```
:: Now execute the rest of the arguments, if any:
shift
if @%1 == @ goto :eof
set command=
:BuildCommand
if @%1 == @ goto :CommandFinished
set "command=%command% %1"
shift
goto :BuildCommand
:CommandFinished
%command%
```

Comment: Could you not assign all the arguments to a variable then use string substitution to remove the first one.

Comment: Hmm, sounds like a potential way forward.  But without the power of proper regexes, I'm not sure I would know how to handle potential quotes and spaces appropriately with this approach. Would this work for `SelectPython "C:\Program Files\Oh god why did I install it here\Python27" python -c "print 'hello'"`  ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

build your own "%*" (I named it `%params%`):

```
set "params="
:build
if @%1==@ goto :cont
shift
set "params=%params% %1"
goto :build
:cont
echo params are %params%
```

Comment: This worked pretty well for me. The only thing it doesn't handle is an empty-string argument and anything that follows it. For example, `python -c "import sys; print(repr(sys.argv[1:]))"  "" ""` correctly receives and prints out its two empty-string arguments. When filtered through this test, it does not receive anything after the first empty-string.  Can you think of a way to handle that?

Comment: See my edit. (that was too easy - I'm quite sure, I missed something...)

Comment: OK, that worked.  I'm not sure why it worked: under some circumstances I've seen `if %1==something` fail with a syntax error when `%1` contains a space, and yet this seems to survive that eventuality.  Anyway, now I think all the bases are covered - many thanks!

Comment: if there were a space, the second word would be `%2`. Except there are surrounding qoutes, but then `if` is still safe because of the quotes.

Answer (score 2):

Just a slight variation from Mofi's example but protects against removing any extra arguments by using the batch file name as part of all the arguments and then remove the batch file and argument 1.

```
@echo off
set all_args=%~f0%*
call set exe_arg=%%all_args:%~f0%1 =%%
echo %exe_arg%
pause
```

Ultimately though if you want to save a few centi seconds using Delayed Expansion is faster then using CALL or using SHIFT.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set all_args=%~f0%*
set exe_arg=!all_args:%~f0%1 =!
echo %exe_arg%
```

Comment: ...or I suppose you could use whatever other "salt" that you think is unlikely to occur in the wild, instead of `%0`

Comment: @jez, I suppose so but the odds of the script having the batch file name and argument 1 combined together with no space as another argument are probably slim to none.  Would probably make it even more foolproof to use `%~f0`

Comment: @jez, or just use a random number. `set rnd=%random%%random%`

Comment: @Squashman Very good idea to include argument 0 or any other not typical string in parameters list and string substitution to avoid that argument 1 string is removed more than once from parameter list.

Answer (score 1):

The batch code according to idea of [Squashman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1417694/squashman)

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set "LOC=%1"
set "AllParameters=%*"
set "AllButFirst=!AllParameters:%LOC% =!"
echo Remaining: %AllButFirst%
endlocal
pause
```

This produces for

```
"C:\Program Files\Oh god why did I install it here\Python27" python -c "print 'hello'"
```

the expected output

```
python -c "print 'hello'"
```

Problem with this code: If the directory path (first pararameter) is found also on one more parameter, it is also removed from the other parameter because substitution removes all occurrences of the searched string and not just first occurrence.

Comment: Yes.  That is what I wast thinking.  You could also get rid of the delayed expansion and use `call set AllButFirst=%%AllParameters:%LOC% =%%`